Dependencies for QT Creator using qmake
When I use QT Creator, I am in. Pro file includes include.pri file, but when I really compiled, I reported an error, saying that I could not find the header file in the corresponding environment, the following is some of my code and the corresponding error information, I do not know how to solve this problem, and why this problem occurs.
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

include (D:/data/opencv-4.10.0/opencv-4.10.0/_build/opencv.pri)


INCLUDEPATH += D:/data/opencv-4.10.0/opencv-4.10.0/_build/install/include
Debug:{
    LIBS += -lD:/data/opencv-4.10.0/opencv-4.10.0/_build/install/x64/vc17/lib/opencv_world4100d
}
Release:{
    LIBS += -lD:/data/opencv-4.10.0/opencv-4.10.0/_build/install/x64/vc17/lib/opencv_world4100
}


:-1: error: dependent '..\..\..\..\..\..\data\opencv-4.10.0\opencv-4.10.0\_build\install\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp' does not exist.

I tried adding an -I parameter to my includepath, using relative paths, etc., but it didn't work

The problem has been resolved, mainly due to incorrect automatic dependency environment addition under the Windows environment. Simply adding the dependpath configuration is enough. I'm not yet clear why the automatic association failed.
INCLUDEPATH += D:/lib/include
DEPENDPATH += D:/lib/include
Debug:{
    LIBS += -lD:/lib/x64/vc17/lib/opencv_world4100d
}
Release:{
    LIBS += -lD:/lib/x64/vc17/lib/opencv_world4100
}

